# How to make some elements of mainWindow common in other views?

Tags: wpf, window

I've got standard MainWindow.xaml. Then I added some pages which I wanted to show in the MainWindow. There are some common elements for all views, for example, header text, header image, and the name of logged user. How can I set these elements on the MainWindow that will be visible when another view is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Set the appropriate items in the resources.
Properties that need these values will be able to get them using DynamicResource.

But it will be much better if you implement the Solution in the MVVM pattern.
Then you won't even have such a task (to transfer data between views).

Comment: I thought there might be something like MasterPage in WebForms.